# Align the text that's inside the <img> tag?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I have

**HTML**

```
<div class="avatar">
<img src="$USER_AVATAR_URL$" /><a href="$LOGIN_FORM$" /></a>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to align the login form to the right of the image. Currently it's below the image. I've tried using text-align and it didn't help. So how would I go about doing this?

**CSS**

```
.avatar { 
 float: right; 
 background: #242426; 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 5px solid #242426; 
 border-radius: 50%;
 position:absolute;
 top: 60px;
 right:250px;
}

.avatar img {
 display: block; 
 width: 100%; 
 border: 0; 
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
 float:right;
}
```

Comment: Btw why is there backslash in the `<a href="$LOGIN_FORM$" />` ? `<a>` is a pair tag - `<a href=""></a>` u don't put backslash in the first part.

Comment: Actually now I'm not sure what u want to do. Because from the code it looks like u want to have a login form inside of the 50*50 avatar circle and from what u describe I think u want to have a form next to the avatar on the right. Can u draw us what is your idea - how u want the output of code look like?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/aZZtHRo.png

Comment: well u can't put the form inside the avatar class in that case ofc. I will try to write and answer :]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `float: right;` only at the link and `float: left;` to the img

**EDIT**

Something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css"> 
        .avatar { 
             background: #242426; 
             width: 100px;
             height: 100px;
             border: 5px solid #242426; 
             border-radius: 50%;
             position:absolute;
             top: 60px;
             right:250px;
             float:right;
        }

        .class_img {
             float:left;
             display: block; 
             border: 0; 
             margin: 0;
             border-radius: 50%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="avatar">
            <div class="class_img">
            <img src="$USER_AVATAR_URL$" />
            </div>
            <a href="$LOGIN_FORM$" /></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand you. Could you explain that more?

Comment: me neither. Can you make a sketch

Comment: Check the edit...you have to check and adapt it but I think it will be a starting point

Comment: @Zevoxa can u stop writing `<a href="LoginformLink" />Login Form</a>` and start writing `<a href="LoginformLink">Login Form</a>` ? ... (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Answer (score 0):

U should just make a `block` div and `float` the `img` to left and the form to right.

### HTML:

```
<div class="avatarAndLogin">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="$USER_AVATAR_URL$" /></div>
    <div class="login"><a href="$LOGIN_FORM$">login form</a></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.avatarAndLogin{    
 position:absolute;
 top: 60px;
 right:250px;    
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; // need some size here so u can float the avatar and login form inside this block
}

.avatar { 
 margin:0;
 float: left; 
 text-align: center;
 background: #242426; 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 5px solid #ccc; // with light gray border just to show that it's there
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.login{  
 margin:0;
 width: 240px;  
 height: 50px;   
 float: right; 
}
```

Edit how u want. I think it works approximately how u wanted it to.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/Nnjhp/41/ - I used your avatar as a the avatar image.